# Repeat an action set in Photoshop

Tags: adobe, photoshop, photoshop-script

I have an action set in Photoshop that I would like to repeat infinitely.

As the image below, the action set runs 8 batch processes and then ends.

Is it possible to run the action set (F8) automatically again after the last script in the action set has completed?

I have considered using a .bat file to press F8 and use a JSX to call that BAT file at the end of the action set, however, I cannot get this to work so far.

Any help is really appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Why not run action in JSX instead of running bat that runs action..? Also you surely want it to finish at some point otherwise PS will freeze, no?

Comment: I also question you wanting it to *repeat infinitely*. A script could be written to process all files in a folder. You really don't want to put Photoshop in a infinite loop ;)

Comment: I have solved this issue now. I was only looking to implement an infinite loop as I have written a script to exit when there are no folders left to process. Thank you for your comments.